# Erro no imap_qprint

Tags: php, imap

Alguém sabe o porque desse erro quando usa *imap_qprint*.

```
$body = imap_qprint(imap_body($mailbox,$i));
```

> Notice: Unknown: Invalid quoted-printable sequence: ="UTF-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Ol=C3=A1, busquei por 13 (errflg=3) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Tentei usar utf8 no cabeçalho mas não adiantou. Ajuda aí pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque:

```
$body = imap_qprint(imap_body($mailbox,$i));
```

Por:

```
$body = quoted_printable_decode(imap_body($mailbox,$i));
```

Creio que a única diferença é que o `quoted_printable_decode` não precisa do módulo do *imap* e talvez por isso ele ignore o tipo de "charset" definido na mensagem.

> **Nota:** Os "erros" que começam com `Notice:` não são erros de fato, mas sim um aviso apenas, ele só emite o isso quando todos tipos de erro estão ligados (veja [`E_ALL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php)), em servidores de produção é bem provável que não exiba (e nem deve).